# Fixed footer resizing

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a collapsible sidebar that when expanded, should shrink the entire "contents" section into the remaining space.

This works for everything in the "contents" except for the footer. I currently have it at 100% width and the position fixed to the bottom. When the sidebar is expanded, the width of the footer doesn't change like it's parent "contents" container; the far right portion is just pushed offscreen.

How can I make it so the footer resizes with the rest of the contents?

I have tried removing the position:fixed, and I get the behavior I want but the footer is no longer at the bottom. Is there another way to make the footer stay there while keeping the resizing?

Edit: here is a JSFiddle that shows the problem.

```
#footer {
position:fixed;
}
```

is set right now.
http://jsfiddle.net/2btq791r/8/

Comment: Please provide the code you have so far so others can help. Visit [how to submit a question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: @jfeferman Thank you, I have added a JSFiddle

Answer (score 0):

```css
html {
  height: 100%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

*,
*:before,
*:after {
  box-sizing: inherit;
}

body {
  position: relative;
  margin: 0;
  padding-bottom: 6rem;
  min-height: 100%;
  font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Arial, sans-serif;
}

.demo {
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding-top: 64px;
  max-width: 640px;
  width: 94%;
}

.demo h1 {
  margin-top: 0;
}

/**
 * Footer Styles
 */

.footer {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  padding: 1rem;
  background-color: #efefef;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
 <div class="row">
  <div class="demo">
      <h1>CSS “Always on the bottom” Footer</h1>

      <p>I often find myself designing a website where the footer must rest at the bottom of the page, even if the content above it is too short to push it to the bottom of the viewport naturally.</p>

      <p>However, if the content is taller than the user’s viewport, then the footer should disappear from view as it would normally, resting at the bottom of the page (not fixed to the viewport).</p>

      <p>If you know the height of the footer, then you should set it explicitly, and set the bottom padding of the footer’s parent element to be the same value (or larger if you want some spacing).</p>

      <p>This is to prevent the footer from overlapping the content above it, since it is being removed from the document flow with <code>position: absolute;</code>.</p>
    </div>

    <div class="footer">
      This footer will always be positioned at the bottom of the page, but <strong>not fixed</strong>.
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for this code snippet, which might provide some limited, immediate help. A [proper explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762/349538) would greatly improve its long-term value by showing why this is a good solution to the problem and would make it more useful to future readers with other, similar questions. Please [edit] your answer to add some explanation, including the assumptions you’ve made.